# Teamcity: Statistics on number of failed builds per user

Tags: sql, reporting, teamcity

We are using Teamcity 8.0.5 for our CI server. TeamCity database is SQL Server and I'm trying to get some statistics out of the database directly, i.e. for third party reporting tool.

The report I'm trying to write is number of failed builds per user, or in other words who is the worst human being in the dev-team.

But I could not find this information in the database. There is `build_problem` table with `build_state_id` and `problem_id`. There is `problem` table with description and a bunch of other seemingly related tables:

```
select * 
from build_problem bp
    inner join problem p on bp.problem_id = p.problem_id
    inner join build_state s on bp.build_state_id = s.id
```

But I can't find a link from `problem` table (which I believe represents failed build) to a user who made the check-in.

Any pointers in the right direction of the database structure will be appreciated!